# could not find driver Laravel + Xampp Ubunutu

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Okay, I could open mysql by specifying the full path to it as /opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root In php my admin it also created a table.
But when I run php artisan migrate it gives and error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL:
>   select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema =
>   laraveltest and table_name = migrations)

How can I point that I want to use mysql driver from my xampp?
    Any help would be appreciated
    In env file I have this
    127.0.0.5 is where it located in my hosts file.

```
> APP_NAME=Laravel APP_ENV=local APP_KEY=base64:tOMgf9myAlC7uUDxVH9CHXQLqc7fgfxgv697j0jqGMg=
> APP_DEBUG=true APP_URL=127.0.0.5
> 
> LOG_CHANNEL=stack
> 
> DB_CONNECTION=mysql DB_HOST=127.0.0.5 DB_PORT=3306
> DB_DATABASE=laraveltest DB_USERNAME=root DB_PASSWORD=
> 
> BROADCAST_DRIVER=log CACHE_DRIVER=file SESSION_DRIVER=file
> SESSION_LIFETIME=120 QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
> 
> REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.5 REDIS_PASSWORD=null REDIS_PORT=6379
> 
> MAIL_DRIVER=smtp MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io MAIL_PORT=2525
> MAIL_USERNAME=null MAIL_PASSWORD=null MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
> 
> PUSHER_APP_ID= PUSHER_APP_KEY= PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
> PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
> 
> MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
> MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Here is config/database.php

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.5'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

Comment: What's in your database config?

Comment: 'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

Comment: You need to use the `mysqli` driver, not `mysql`